# How to create an XML?

Tags: xml, haxe

I'm having troubles creating the very simple XML file.
XML I need:

```
<data>
     <id>111</id>
     <message>hello</message>
     <something>...</something>
</data>
```

I'm doing it in such a way:

```
var xml = Xml.createElement("data");

var id = Xml.createElement('id');
id.nodeValue = "111"
xml.addChild(id);

var message = Xml.createElement('message');
message.nodeValue = "hello"
xml.addChild(message);

var message = Xml.createElement('message');
message.nodeValue = "...";
xml.addChild(message);
```

But this doesn't work.
How do I simply set the node value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that nodeValue doesnt apply to elements (http://api.haxe.org/Xml.html) so you would need to add a child text node to it using `createPCData`, eg:

```
var xml = Xml.createElement("data");

var id = Xml.createElement('id');
id.addChild(Xml.createPCData("111"));
xml.addChild(id);

var message = Xml.createElement('message');
message.addChild(Xml.createPCData("hello"));
xml.addChild(message);

var something = Xml.createElement('something');
something.addChild(Xml.createPCData("..."));
xml.addChild(something);
```

That should then work as you expect. Once you have created the text node then you can use `nodeValue` on that (should you want to), for example:

```
var somethingElse = Xml.createElement('somethingElse');
var textNode = Xml.createPCData("theText");
textNode.nodeValue = "newText";
somethingElse.addChild(textNode);
xml.addChild(somethingElse);
```

Ive created a simple test here: http://try.haxe.org/#104d0

Hope that helps.